# No funciona menú hamburguesa con Materialize

Tags: css, materialize, responsive

Alguien sabe por qué no me funciona el menú de hamburguesa al implementarlo con Materialize. Me aparece el icono, pero al seleccionarlo no pasa nada, sólo aparece en la url un # y se supone que tengo todo correctamente, tanto el código de la navegación, como los archivos css y js de Materialize.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <!-- My Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/styles.css">
    <!-- FontAwesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>

    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper red">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
                <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
                    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
                    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
                    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
                    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo necesitas agregar un script a la clase donde se va a activar el menú, con un: `$(".button-collapse").sideNav();` dentro de una etiqueta `<script></script>`

```
<script> $(".button-collapse").sideNav(); </script>
```

**Aquí el ejemplo completo** (ejecutalo)**:**

```html
<html>

<head>
    <!-- My Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/styles.css">
    <!-- FontAwesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>

    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper red">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
                <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
                    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
                    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
                    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
                    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>$(".button-collapse").sideNav();</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Me podrías indicar dónde pondría el script en el código real, antes lo había puesto, pero igual seguía sin funcionar.

Comment: agregalo dentro de una etiqueta `<script>` edité la respuesta, al final del código lo verás.

Comment: Mucha gracias, ahora sí funcionó :D